# unable to find an inherited method for function ‘writeRaster’ for signature ‘"data.frame", "character"’

Tags: methods, inherited

I am trying to save .csv raster file from the data.frame but an error occurs.

```
library(dismo)
sp <- gbif("Neurergus ","kaiseri")   
sp <- sp[sp$basisOfRecord %in% c("HUMAN_OBSERVATION", "OBSERVATION", "PRESERVED_SPECIMEN"), c("lon", "lat")]    
sp$species <- 1   
sp <- na.omit(sp)

writeRaster(spg, "zzz.csv")

#Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
#  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘writeRaster’ for signature ‘"data.frame", "character"’
```

Comment: this problem occurred in Rstudio

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want to write a `data.frame` to a `.csv` file. You should use `write.csv` for that.

```
write.csv(spg, "zzz.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

`writeRaster` is for writing raster data.